# Creating a new schema at startup

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class with a custom schema mapping:

```
class Book {
    String title
    static mapping = {
        table name: 'table_book', schema: 'books'
    }
}
```

I now get an error at startup (`table_book` could not be created beacuse schema `books` doesn't exist). Should GORM realise this and create the `books` schema? If not, how can I create this schema at startup (from an event I guess)?

Comment: is your DatabaseConfig in update mode?

Comment: no, it is in create-drop (just playing in development at the moment)

Comment: Can the db user you have configured in DatabaseConfig create a new Schema in the DB? The db user have sufficient rights?

Comment: yes, the user can create the schema